# Any way of forcing a function with Math.random to return the same value in an expression?

Tags: javascript

Recently started learning Javascript as a complete newbie to programming. I'm running into an issue while making a Horror film picker that will randomly pick a film from an array, as well as show the picture corresponding to it in a sliding tab.

This is the relevant code for the message(films array is way longer, but can only post two links):

```
var films = [
["Lake Mungo", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/68/Lake_Mungo_Official_Poster.jpg"],
["A Tale of Two Sisters", "http://www.thenightmarenetwork.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/tale2sisters.png"]
];

function pickFilm() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * films.length);
}

function showFilm(){
$("#newreplyDiv").append("<img src='" + films[pickFilm()][1] + "'><span id='movieText'><h1>The next film you're watching is: " + films[pickFilm()][0] + " !</h1><h2>" +
"Hope you enjoy it and try to sleep at night alright?</h2></span>")
}
```

Is there any way of making it return both values for the same index of the array? This version returns a random movie name, then a random picture, not the one in the same sub array, and assigning the value to a function before just locks the value to that index, I need it to be random each time the user clicks the button.

Thank you in advance for any help provided, there probably is a really easy way of fixing it :)

Comment: Make a variable inside the showFilm function (`var pickedFilm = pickFilm();`) and use that variable two times (`films[pickedFilm][1]`)?

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a variable inside the showFilm function to store the random pick, then reuse that:

```
function showFilm(){
    var pickedFilm = pickFilm();
    $("#newreplyDiv").append("<img src='" + films[pickedFilm][1] + "'><span id='movieText'><h1>The next film you're watching is: " + films[pickedFilm][0] + " !</h1><h2>" +
    "Hope you enjoy it and try to sleep at night alright?</h2></span>")
}
```